# Is there a way to stave off the 'script taking too long' error?

Tags: javascript

I've got a page that renders a lot of data and hits the 'script taking too long' wall.

This is a personal project, so I'm not concerned about user experience.

When I 'comment out' 20% of the data it runs fine, it's just the last few bunch of points that push it over the edge. It times out after - I dunno - 15 seconds?

I have experimented with optimizing the rendering - including various attempts to thin out the data - and it turns out that's going to be more work than I have time for right now, I'd really just like to get the render working for now and circle back.

**Is there anything I can do to defeat - or at least temporarily adjust the duration of - that timeout? I am using Chrome. Hoping there's some configuration or developer setting or something.**

Comment: Consider chunking the processing of the data and separating the chunks via `setTimeout`/`setInteval`. This may work if you can independently process data, so you don't do it all at once. The error shows up if a takes too long. E.g., over 10s (not sure on the exact number). But if you do multiple 5s processings, it'd be satisfied.

Comment: Yes, optimization of code will have to wait. For now I'm looking for a way to reconfigure the browser or somesuch.

Comment: Not sure if it's an option for your case but In Chrome, you can access the Developer Tools settings and increase the timeout duration. To do this, open the Developer Tools menu by pressing F12, then click on the Settings icon (the cogwheel at the top right of the developer tools window). In the General tab, there is a section called Network Throttling at the bottom. Here, you can increase the Network Throttle setting to a value that will allow the render to complete before the timeout occurs.

Comment: Does all the data need to be loaded up front? You could always load data later, maybe on scroll when you reach a certain section or something like that

Comment: Network throttling adds latency. i.e. a delay - to simulate a slow connection. Not what I want.

Comment: If optimizing the code isn't an option, I feel like you're pretty limited... You can also try using a browser extension such as Fiddler or Charles to help debug and optimize the requests and data being sent to the browser. Lighthouse can also help identify potential issues and areas for optimization.